# Select one line of each code

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I've got a Table that stores messages
like this:
codMsg, message, anotherCod

```
1, 'hi', 1
2, 'hello', 1
3, 'wasup', 1
4, 'yo', 2
5, 'yeah', 2
6, 'gogogo', 3
```

I was wondering if is possible to select top 1 of each anotherCod

What I expect:

```
1, 'hi', 1
4, 'yo', 2
6, 'gogogo', 3
```

I want the whole line, not just the number of the anotherCod, so group by should not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mytable.*
from mytable
join (select min(codMsg) as codMsg, anotherCod from mytable group by 2) x    
    on mytable.codMsg = x.codMsg
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2005+, Oracle :

```
SELECT codMsg, 
       message, 
       anotherCod
FROM
(
    SELECT codMsg, 
           message, 
           anotherCod,  
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY anotherCod ORDER BY codMsg ASC) AS Rank
    FROM mytable
) tmp
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: +1 : If windowed functions are available to you, I'd definitely go this route.  Note that RANK() *can* give multiple rows the same value if tied in the ORDER BY, where as ROW_NUMBER() would arbitrarily order them into different positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  myTable
WHERE
  codMSG = (SELECT MIN(codMsg) FROM myTable AS lookup WHERE anotherCod = myTable.anotherCod)
```